# google maps infowindow displays the same content

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

So google maps infowindow always displays the content of the last map item. Based on some research I stumbled accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475830/google-maps-api-v3-markers-all-share-the-same-infowindow). However it still doesn't work for me here is my code.

```
 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, html) {
    marker.addListener('click', function () {
    infowindow.setContent(html);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
 }

for (var x = 0; x < filtered_pins.length; x++) {
var links = filtered_pins[x].description + '<a href="' + filtered_pins[x].slug + '">read more..</a>';

links_arr.push(links);


    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + filtered_pins[x].city + '&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        //console.log('4th'+ links);
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        //marker.addListener('click', function () {
            //infoWindow.setContent(links);
        //    infowindow.open(map, this);
        //});

        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, links);
        my_markers.push(marker);
    });
}
```

I have gone through quite a number of related items on Stackoverflow but they don't seem to be of service.They all seem to already have access to the latlang so their structure is different. I have to use the .getJson method to retrieve an addresses latlang first then create markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iteration of your `for` loop calls `$.getJSON()`, however there is only a single `links` variable that every iteration shares. The `for` loop runs to completion before any of the `$.getJSON()` calls ever call your callback function. So all of them use the last value that was assigned into `links`.

It really is exactly the same problem as in the question you linked to; in the code in that question the problem variable is `club`. The reason the solution from that question didn't work is that your code has the `$.getJSON()` call which is asynchronous, just as the `click` handler is asynchronous.

To fix this, you can simply move the entire loop body into a function. The local variables inside that function will all be unique to each iteration of the loop.

The use of `filtered_pins[x]` seems OK here, but this could also be a problem if it were used inside the `$.getJSON()` callback, and it makes the code simpler to only have that at one point, where `addMarker()` is called.

And at this point you don't need `bindInfoWindow()` to be a separate function, so I moved it inline.

I also made a couple of other little changes to keep the line lengths shorter.

```
for (var i = 0; i < filtered_pins.length; i++) {
    addMarker( filtered_pins[i] );
}

function addMarker( pin ) {
    var links = pin.description +
        '<a href="' + pin.slug + '">read more..</a>';
    links_arr.push(links);

    var url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' +
        pin.city + '&sensor=false';
    $.getJSON( url, null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
        });
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        marker.addListener('click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(links);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

        my_markers.push(marker);
    });
}
```

I'm not sure what the `links_arr` and `my_markers` arrays are used for, so there could be some problems there as well, depending.

In modern browsers, you could also fix this by using `let` instead of `var` for your variables inside the loop. Then you wouldn't need the `addMarkers()` function. But I think this separate function makes the code cleaner, and it's still compatible with old browsers.

Comment: Brilliant thank you it worked. Not sure why this works and moving the contents of the function into my forloop does not.